# run a script in background process with resume capability

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I have a python script which runs in my windows command line to do some automatic tasks. But I want to do this job with resume capability so that if network fails it can be resumed and carry on the further job...
We have "Screen" in Linux to do that background process.
I am looking for a solution for windows

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a script you're trying to "run forever" in Windows, with or without a user logged in, the two options are usually:

1 - Schedule it to run occasionally as a scheduled task without a loop.

2 - Loop it and grab [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) (non-sucking service manager) to handle logging, starting, and stopping as a service.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. In linux we use "screen" to hold any job so that we can start from that state. I am looking for such solution